# Extracting numbers and characters from a text file in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm reading in a text config file in swift and need to extract the numbers and decimals from an ip address. The config.txt file contains the line- *ip address: 192.0.168.1*

So far I have-

```
let path = "/config.txt"

    do {
        // Use contentsOfFile overload.
        // ... Specify ASCII encoding.
        // ... Ignore errors.
        let data = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        // If a value was returned, print it.


        let str = data
        let intString = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet
                .decimalDigitCharacterSet()
                .invertedSet)
            .joinWithSeparator("")

        print(data)
        print(intString)
     } catch {
   }
```

Of course this will return just the numbers of the ip address. I'm stumped at getting the correct format of 192.0.168.1

Comment: have you received an array of 192,0,168,1 ??

Comment: currently, what gets printed to output is- ip address: 172.19.24.28
172192428

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's *always* the same `"ip address: "` text before the IP address, then it's super simple:

```
let str = "ip address: 192.0.168.1"

if let intString = str.componentsSeparatedByString("address: ").last {
    print(intString)
}
```

Prints:

> 192.0.168.1